# Mirror screen to Samsung Smart TV

Tags: streaming, mirroring, smart-tv

I want to mirror my PC screen to my new Samsung Smart TV.
Miracast is unavailable. Are there other options? I don't want to stream just pictures or videos. My entire screen should be broadcasted live.

Answer (score 0):

If your tv is in 20 meters range from PC then you can use HDMI cable to make a connection between them. Next, on PC you must set screen mirroring and on tv select hdmi input.